# Robotium: How to automate button click in the RecyclerView row?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-recyclerview, robotium

I am using **Robotium** (Version: 5.5.3). I have a button in the row of RecyclerView. I want to automate the clicking of that button on a specific row.

```
solo.clickInRecyclerView(index);  only automates the clicking of that whole row.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please care to explain the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().getFragmentAtPosition(count-1)
```

This would give you the topmost (current) fragment.
Then cast it into the desired fragmnet. eg.

```
MyFrag myCurrentFrag = (MyFrag) ....
```

Then using it, get the adapter or recylerview.
Once you have the desired recylerview instance, make use of

```
RelativeLayout myRel = (RelativeLayout) getchildAt();
Button btn = (button) myRel.findViewById();
btn.performClick();
```

Comment: RecyclerView myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) solo.getView(R.id.recyclerView);
            solo.waitForView(myRecyclerView);
            View vg = myRecyclerView.getChildAt(2);
            Button btn = (Button) vg.findViewById(R.id.btn); Here last line gives nullpointerexception.

Comment: can you debug or via log, check children of your recyclerview.
is there any child at pos:2?

if yes, check what type of view is vg